# How to convert string arrays in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, matrix

I am pretty new to javascript.I am pretty confused that how to convert this manipulated string array in to actual array.Since its not an actual array this program throw

```
console.log(line)//[10,0],[80,0],[20,0],[11,20],
var MatrixAJobtime =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("["+line+"]"));
console.log(arrdateline)//[10,0],[80,0],[20,0],[11,20],
var MatrixBJobDeadLine = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("["+arrdateline+"]"));;


console.log(_.isArray(MatrixAJobtime)) //False

var m1 = MatrixAJobtime 
    m2 =MatrixBJobDeadLine 
    result = m1.map((a,i) => a.map((n,j) => n - m2[i][j]));



console.log(result);//[ [ -90, -36, -45 ], [ 8, -36, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0 ] ]
```

> result = m1.map((a,i) => a.map((n,j) => n - m2[i][j]));
>                   ^ TypeError: m1.map is not a function

Comment: That throws me a error

Comment: @wrarar : yo need to remove the last `,` .... `var MatrixAJobtime =  JSON.parse("[" + line.slice(0,-1) + "]");`  and `var MatrixBJobDeadLine = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify("[" + arrdateline.slice(0,-1) + "]"));`

Comment: Given that `var line = "[10,0],[80,0],[20,0],[11,20]"`, then you will get a proper array when you do `var MatrixAJobtime =  JSON.parse(("["+line+"]"));`

Comment: where do you get line from? it is easier, not to use string representation of data id the data in in other genuin format, like array.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the below snippet and check whether this is what you are requesting..

```js
var line = [[10,0],[80,0],[20,0],[11,20]];

line = line.map(function(arr){
  arr = arr.map(function(a){
    return a.toString();
  });
  
  return arr;
});

console.log(line);// prints: [["10","0"],["80","0"],["20","0"],["11","20"]]
```